# Issue with running a circuit: Cannot read property 'idCode' of null

Tags: programming, circuit-construction

I have been trying to run simple circuits from the Circuit Composer, both on a real quantum comp and on a simulator. Every time I get this error message:

```
Could not run circuit ""
Cannot read property 'idCode' of null
```

Could you please clarify what this means? I tried logging out and in, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What software environment do you refer to?

Comment: I have been running the Circuit Composer online from the IBM quantum computing website via Microsoft Edge. Tried Google Chrome - same result.

Comment: Is it possible that I have run out of a max number of circuits that I am allowed to test without a paid subscription?